SB3 for imitation learning. How to force demonstration action at given state?
I am trying to train a RL agent using SB3 (PPO algorithm), Gymnasium, and PyTorch.
As the dynamics of the environment is quite complex, I have a dataset of about 200 trajectories that I can use as demonstrations. My idea is to use those at training time so that, every n episodes, a demonstration is injected. When that happens, I force the reset method of the environment to sample from the dataset. However, I have difficulties in forcing the expert action I know should be executed.
More or less, I think I found the point where I should implement this. The following method is implemented in the ActorCriticPolicy(BasePolicy) class of policies.py in SB3.
def forward(self, obs: th.Tensor, deterministic: bool = False) -> Tuple[th.Tensor, th.Tensor, th.Tensor]:
    """
    Forward pass in all the networks (actor and critic)

    :param obs: Observation
    :param deterministic: Whether to sample or use deterministic actions
    :return: action, value and log probability of the action
    """
    # Preprocess the observation if needed
    features = self.extract_features(obs)
    if self.share_features_extractor:
        latent_pi, latent_vf = self.mlp_extractor(features)
    else:
        pi_features, vf_features = features
        latent_pi = self.mlp_extractor.forward_actor(pi_features)
        latent_vf = self.mlp_extractor.forward_critic(vf_features)
    # Evaluate the values for the given observations
    values = self.value_net(latent_vf)
    distribution = self._get_action_dist_from_latent(latent_pi)
    actions = distribution.get_actions(deterministic=deterministic)
    log_prob = distribution.log_prob(actions)
    actions = actions.reshape((-1, *self.action_space.shape))  # type: ignore[misc]
    return actions, values, log_prob

I guess I have to force a logic such that, if I am running a demonstration, actions and log_prob should be overridden. The way would be to have access the environment variables, where I have a class variable that saves the action that should be executed next (if running a demonstration).
I am aware of the Imitation library, however, I think what I want to do is not available in it.
Is there a way to make it done?
